# Append PowerShell function args to program invoked by the function

Tags: powershell

I'm wondering how I can append PowerShell function arguments to a program command?

I want something like this:

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  docker run $x $y $z
}
```

So that calling `PS>foo` alone would be the equivelant to `PS>docker run`, and `PS>foo a b c` to `PS>docker run a b c`.

This seems like a question that must have an answer here somewhere, but I am unable to find it. I'm not sure whether I'm just phrasing my searches poorly. Apologies in advance if so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab the argument values from `$PSBoundParameters.Values`:

```
function foo($x, $y, $z) {
  docker run $PSBoundParameters.Value
}
```

---

As pointed out in the comments, `$PSBoundParameters` doesn't guarantee insertion order, an alternative approach would be to take a single argument of arrays with the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` parameter flag set:

```
function foo {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromRemainingArgumemnts)]
    [string[]]$dockerArgs
  )

  $dockerArgs = @('run';$dockerArgs)
  & docker $dockerArgs
}
```

Comment: Dictionary does not guaranty insertion order.